# What is the difference between cscope.out & ctags file

Tags: c, linux, ctags, cscope

I am aware of the difference between the two tools, cscope & ctags & when to use which one of them. What I am trying to ask is about their database file.

By default, `cscope` creates `cscope.out` as its database file, whereas `ctags` creates `tags` in the directory it runs in.

1. Is there any major difference between them? I believe there is, because the sizes are largely different. cscope.out is about 6-7 times larger than tags.
2. Can one application use the db file created by another?
3. Is there any way to convert between them? (If option 2 is not possible.)

Why I want this?: While working with LARGE codes, like kernel source code or so, it takes long time, to create 2 files. If possible I wanted to use same file for both.

I am limiting the scope of this question to C as programming language. So it's sufficient if the 2 tools look only at `.c .h and .s` files.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934233/cscope-or-ctags-why-choose-one-over-the-other

Shortly: the main difference is that ctags does not store each function call (but definition only), but cscope does. Ctags can store some extra info that could help with omnicompletion (in Vim's terms), but cscope does not.

Comment: So except for omnicompletion part, ctags is a subset of cscope data?

Comment: It seems, but I'm not sure since I actually used ctags only, and just looked into cscope out of curiosity.

Comment: 'long time' might be well spent, i use both for navigating kernel sources, tags for definitions and auto-completion, cscope for finding function calls while refactoring (and usage examples)

Comment: Normally, I hardly do any kernel changes. So autocomplete is not so critical requirement. The problem is if I do change some file, it will try to refresh the cscope.out file, if run as `cscope -R`. Besides, I don't mind if the tags are _slightly misaligned_, because of editing of the source.

Comment: what is _it_ in `it will try to refresh the cscope.out file`? does editor refresh it automatically for you?

Comment: No, whenever I quit & start cscope from command line, it will retry to create database file. Or maye it just loads the db file, which takes time for kernel code.